# php Real-Time form post submit

Tags: php, html, mysql

Let me explain what I want to.

I want to add a value in a list with db add without page change when I input in `form`, and click `submit`.

but in this code, I must refresh one more time to add, and also added twice a time.

How can I do that?

```
<?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','MYID','MYPASS','MYDB');
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM MYTABLE";
    $rs = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    $list = '';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs)) {
            $list = $list."<li><a href=\"index.php?id={$row['id']}\">{$row['title']}</a></li>";
    }

    $article = array(
        'title' => 'Welcome!',
        'description' => 'Hello, Web!'
    );

    if (isset($_GET['id'])){
        $filtered_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['id']);

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM topic WHERE id={$filtered_id}";
        $rs = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs);
        $article['title'] = $row['title'];
        $article['description'] = $row['description'];
    }

    if ($_POST['title'] != null){
        $sql_in = "INSERT INTO topic (title, description, created) VALUES ('{$_POST['title']}', '{$_POST['description']}', NOW())";

        $rs_in = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_in);

        if ($rs_in === false) {
                $msg = mysqli_error($conn);
        } else {
                $msg = 'Success.';
        }
    } else {
        $msg = 'Fill in';
    }
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
        <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <title>WEB</title>
        </head>

        <body>
                <h1><a href="index.php">WEB</a></h1>
                <ol>
                        <?=$list?>
                </ol>
                <details>
                        <summary>Create</summary>
                        <form action="./index.php" method="POST">
                                <p><input type="txt" name="title" placeholder="title"></p>
                                <p><textarea name="description" placeholder="description"></textarea></p>
                                <p><input type="submit"></p>
                                <p><?=$msg?></p>
                        </form>
                </details>
        </body>
</html>
                <h2><?=$article['title']?></h2>
                <?=$article['description']?>
        </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In php realtime isn't a thing but there is a workaround you can use events services like pusher https://pusher.com/docs and receive the events in client side instantly .

there other website offers this so do your search before choosing them also you can always build your event server in node.js , c# , go

Comment: Oh.... No realtime.... ok then I'll use another language. thanks

Answer (score 0):

To add a value to a list in a database without refreshing the page, you can use AJAX with jQuery or JavaScript. You can create a form with an input field and a submit button, and then use AJAX to send the data to the server without refreshing the page. Here are the general steps:

1. Create a form with an input field and a submit button.
2. Use jQuery or JavaScript to listen for the submit event on the form.
3. When the form is submitted, use **AJAX** to send the data to the server.
4. On the server, insert the data into the database.
5. Return a response from the server to indicate whether the insertion was successful or not.
6. Use jQuery or JavaScript to update the list on the page with the new value.

You can find many tutorials and examples online that show how to do this, such as the ones on Stack Overflow, GeeksforGeeks, Simplified Coding, and YouTube.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).